# How to assign a variable which function takes as a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm trying to do something like this, but variable is not Assign (

```
const insert = (str, index, pasteString) => {
  let res;
  if (index > 0) {
    res = str.substring(0, index) + pasteString + str.substring(index, str.length);
  } else {
    res = pasteString + str;
  }
  str = res;
}
```

Here's i'm trying to call this function

```
const filterDescription = (obj) => {
  const str = obj.description;
  const strLen = str.length;
  const fifty = Math.ceil(regexIndexOf(/[\/.!;?]/, str, strLen / 2));
  const oneOfFour = Math.ceil(regexIndexOf(/[\/.!;?]/, str, strLen / 4));
  const oneOfThree = Math.ceil(regexIndexOf(/[\/.!;?]/, str, strLen / 3));

  console.log([fifty, oneOfFour, oneOfThree]);
  insert(str, fifty, `string`);
  insert(str, oneOfFour, `string`);
  insert(str, oneOfThree, `string`);
  insert(str, 1, `string`);
  insert(str, strLen - 1, `string`);
  return str;
}
```

Comment: *... but variable is not Assign* — what does that mean? What variable?

Comment: Oh wait; you mean `str`? You cannot do that in JavaScript. You can return the updated value and then assign back to the original variable in the calling environment.

Comment: @Pointy str it's variable

Comment: @Pointy Oh, that's bad, but what about First Class Fuctions (( but which alternatives i have ?

Comment: I don't think "first-class functions" has anything to do with it. Assuming `str` is a string, when you call the function you pass a *copy* of the string. You can re-assign to the `str` parameter in the function but it does not affect the calling environment. The only way to do that is with a `return` value.

Comment: @Pointy, alright, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to set a return on the final of the function:

```
const insert = (str, index, pasteString) => {
    let res;
    if (index > 0) {
        res = str.substring(0, index) + pasteString + str.substring(index, str.length);
    } else {
        res = pasteString + str;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Did you try to do this?

Comment: So, in this case, you can reattribute the value of str out of the function with the value returned from "insert" function. How this function is called? If you want, paste the rest of the code here for clarify for us.

Comment: I believe that in this case, you can pass the variable by reference. For example:
https://pastebin.com/tbSCRN25

Comment: alright thanks i'm change this to array or Object !)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable pointer or betterly said, pass the str variable by reference to the function and the update it.